# VBA apply Formula to an entire column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to  apply an Formula into an entire Row (A)

My code:

```
Sub row()

Dim i As Long

Dim S1 As String

Dim S2 As String

S1 = "=+LINKS(C"
S2 = ";1)"

i = 2

Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert


For i = 2 To 90000

    Range("A" & i).Value = "=+Left(C "" & i & "" ;1)"

Next i

End Sub
```

The error is occuring on: Range("A" & i).Value = "=+Left(C "" & i & "" ;1)"
Error code: '1004'
i can't find a way to put the variable "i" into the Formula...

I want to put into the column "A" the Formula, which lets the Cells in "A" look into the Cell "C" of each individual row and take the first Number and write it in itself.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try `Range("A" & i).Formula= "=Left(C " & i & " ;1)"`?

Comment: yes, i tried: " " , "" "" and """ """